# Can't resolve peer dependencies in node project

Tags: npm, npm-install

```
dev@1d821be6e48f:~/project$ npm i
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@7.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@>=5.0.0 <8.0.0 || ^7.0.0-beta.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN css-loader@2.1.0 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@2.29.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.1.0 || >=2.1.0-dev || >=2.2.0-dev || >=2.3.0-dev || >=2.4.0-dev || >=2.5.0-dev || >=2.6.0-dev || >=2.7.0-dev || >=2.8.0-dev || >=2.9.0-dev || >= 3.0.0-dev || >= 3.1.0-dev but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.6 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.6: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.6 (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.6: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.6 (node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.6: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

added 1 package from 1 contributor, moved 1 package and audited 37762 packages in 7.365s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I see that `package.json` HAS `typescript` and `@angular/compiler-cli`. I dont't get NPM logs... What am i missing?
Here is piece of `package.json`

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
```

How to translate this? `typescript@>=2.1.0` I can't find any good docs concerning version ranges... 
Why `WARN` messages are appearing?

Comment: @NoLogig, i don't remember. Does it matter at all?

Comment: @NoLogig, didn't help

Answer (score 1):

try the below command on cmd

```
npm install -g angular-cli@7.2.0
```

Comment: In Earlier version of npm, we could automatically install the peer dependencies, but after npm 3, this functionality has been removed extensively. Try the mentioned command **npm install -g npm-install-peers** or **npm-install-peers**. If you face the same issue, then delete node_modules directory and reinstall packages or npm install or npm cache clean and npm install